# regexp that returns the first letter and all subsequent consonants

Tags: javascript, regex, perl

What's a regexp that returns the first letter and all subsequent consonants from a word?

In other words it should do

```
"word" => "wrd"
"alliteration" => "alltrtn"
```

Is it possible to do it in one shot? with a substitution?

Ideally in perl but I can translate from Javascript or maybe Python.

Comment: A regular expression always matches a contiguous substring of the input, it can't return anything with gaps.

Comment: Try `"alliteration".replace(/^(.)|[aeiou]/g, '$1');`

Comment: Please add a proper language tag. Regex doesn't exist in a vacuum. While you may be able to translate the regex, the methods you use to apply it will generally be somewhat language specific. For example, the existing answer wouldn't work without significant modifications in Python.

Comment: with perl you could do `perl -pe "s/(^.)|[aeiou]/$1/g" file.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this (javascript):

```
/(?!^)[eyuioa]/g

"word".replace(/(?!^)[eyuioa]/g, ""); // "wrd"
"alliteration".replace(/(?!^)[eyuioa]/g, ""); // "alltrtn"
```

Comment: Not all major browsers support lookbehinds yet.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, you want comment for question, don't you ?

Comment: Why you vote up if I am author ?